# There is only one Core ACTIVE in the Dual Core Verilator when running baremetal or pk programs

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I'm using the dual core build of Verilator(emulator). But I found that only one core is active when I run the baremetal of pk programs using command like this:

```
./emulator-freechips.rocketchip.system-DualCoreConfig baremetal-program
```

or

```
./emulator-freechips.rocketchip.system-DualCoreConfig pk pk-program
```

I built the Verilator using the command shown below:

```
cd rocket-chip/emulator
make CONFIG=DualCoreConfig
```

Thanks a lot for any idea on this!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about this, but in this issue on the rocket-chip repo someone seems to have made some progress: https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/issues/1553. It also might be worth looking at the SiFive Freedom E SDK, maybe there are some multi-core programs there: https://github.com/sifive/freedom-e-sdk

Comment: My understanding is that, by default, the program is run on one core even there are multiple cores. If you understand the system enough you can modify the frontend server (riscv-fesvr) to load multiple programs on different cores and run multiple cores in parallel. On gotcha is the memory mapping. Either fesvr load programs to unoverlapped memory and running in bare-metal or have a simple virtual memory allocator to set different page tables for different cores. Anyway, this seems a lot work to do.

Comment: @WeiSong   Thanks for the answers. I've changed to the ncsim environment to get rid of this problem.